# Accessing specific changeItem using Sharepoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office365, changelog

I'm trying to get an individual change event using;

**GET
* https://{sitecollection}/{personal/user_name_domain_onmicrosoft_com}/_api/web/getchanges('query')/item**

Reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj246759(v=office.12).aspx

And

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246759(v=office.15).aspx

I'm unable to get it working, and I can't find any example of this call.

I'm trying something like;

**GET**

- https://{sitecollection}/{personal/user_name_domain_onmicrosoft_com}/_api/web/getchanges('Add=true,Item=true')/item
- https://{sitecollection}/{personal/user_name_domain_onmicrosoft_com}/_api/web/getchanges(query='Add=true,Item=true')/item

but no luck.

**FYI::** I'm not trying to get changelogs with this call. I'm trying to get an individual change item. But since the syntax is like that I put a random query in the those braces. The /getchanges(which is a POST call) works fine.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two options how to construct request for a `ChangeCollection` endpoint:

**Option 1**

Post `ChangeQuery` via request body

```
function getChanges(webUrl,queryOptions,success,failure)
{
   var changeQueryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' },  
        } 
   };
   for(var key in queryOptions) {
       changeQueryPayload['query'][key] = queryOptions[key];
   }

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(changeQueryPayload),
      url: webUrl + '/_api/web/getchanges', 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}
```

**Option 2**

Pass `ChangeQuery` expression via query string:

```
function getChanges(webUrl,queryOptions, success,failure)
{
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      },
      url: webUrl + '/_api/web/getchanges(@qry)?@qry=' + JSON.stringify(queryOptions) + , 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}
```

**Example**

Retrieve updates for a web:

```
var queryOptions = {"Update":true,"Web":true};


getChanges(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,queryOptions,
  function(result){
      var changes = result.d.results;
      //print info
      console.log('Found ' + changes.length + ' items');   
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
```

Regarding requesting a specific change item, it could be retrieved from a results returned from REST service.

Comment: How above code needs to be written in typescript using httpClient or spHttpClient in react typescript ?
            var query = JSON.stringify( '{"Update":true,"Web":true}');

            const reqH: Headers = new Headers();
            reqH.append('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
            const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
                headers: reqH
            };

            var url = `${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/getChanges`;
            this.httpClient.post(url,HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819(v=office.15).aspx

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getchanges?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ 'query': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' }, 'Web': true, 'Update': true } }",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question. This is a diff call (POST call) and it works fine for me. I'm interested in an individual item (ChangeItem) as you can see the /item at the end of the call I was trying.

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan Were you able to get the individual item ? How did you solve the issue. I am having a similar issue where I need to know the details of the SP.ChangeItem

Comment: I was able to get the individual items but that doesn't return me all the data I want  _api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=Id eq 48

Comment: No, that is the item itself. I was looking for the change event in its entirety. i.e, a change in the changelogs giving all the details about what it was. Right now, I only get the list affected, the item id, the type of change etc. I was looking for something more detailed but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx.

Following code is working for me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getchanges", 
    type: "POST",
    data: "{ 'query': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' },'Web': true, 'Update': true, 'Add': true } }",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",'X-RequestDigest':$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});

function successHandler(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
    alert("successHandler " + "textstatus:" +textStatus + "data: " + data);
}

function errorHandler(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert('Request failed: ' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
}
```